# How to select the last thread group by message

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I'm using symfony 4 and doctrine 2.

I have two entities **Message** and **MessageThread**, MessageThread is related **ManyToOne** to Message.

Now I'd like to select the last thread group by message , I have tried this query **but I get always the first thread**.

```
// MessageThreadRepository.php

public function inbox()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('mt')
        ->leftJoin('mt.message', 'm')
        ->groupBy('mt.message')
        ->orderBy('mt.id', 'desc')
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

var_dump of $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

```
array(3) {
    [0]=>
  array(4) {
        ["id"]=>
    int(10)
        ["body"]=>
    string(2) "ok"
        ["createdAt"]=>
    object(DateTime)#1958 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2019-08-29 16:42:16.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(17)
    ["body"]=>
    string(8) "test msg"
    ["createdAt"]=>
    object(DateTime)#1955 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2019-08-30 00:35:39.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["body"]=>
    string(7) "Hi hous"
    ["createdAt"]=>
    object(DateTime)#1962 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2019-08-29 15:41:11.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post `var_dump($qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult());` before return

Comment: it's done, I have added the var_dump

Comment: "ok" "test msg" and "Hi hous" are MessageThread related to first record of Message? Do you want MessageThread of the last inserted Message?

Comment: @user11504915 what did you think about my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Your problem is on your order by instrunction here `mt.id` become `m.id`

```
public function inbox()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('mt')
        ->leftJoin('mt.message', 'm')
        ->groupBy('mt.message')
        ->orderBy('m.id', 'desc')
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```